# Is there any way to upload a large file (over 2GB) to a webserver through 32bit php?

Tags: php, forms, apache, raspberry-pi

I have a home server set up on a Raspberry Pi 4 running Raspbian Lite. I have built a small webserver on it running Apache and PHP. I have file upload options on this web server that allow me and others to upload files through the web page through a html form that goes to a PHP script that handles the file uploading, updating database, etc.

This server works great for smaller files, however I recently tried to add a file that was around 2GB in size. The webpage would load for over 10 minutes before giving me a "Connection Reset" error.

I have edited both my php.ini and apache2.conf to change all relevant options to allow large file size upload, increase timeouts, etc. I discovered, after much searching, that the problem was that my processor on my server was 32 bit, therefore so was the PHP. Apparently 32 bit PHP doesn't work for uploading files of this size.

I have thought about possible solutions, such as somehow directly uploading via FTP from the html form and bypassing http or somehow splitting the file into smaller pieces while uploading, but I don't know where to start.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: were you able to fix this? Did you check my answer?

Comment: No. The issue lies in the OS that I used (Raspbian Lite) being 32bit. 32bit PHP doesn't support file uploads over 2GB. Changing my configuration files was the first thing I did.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that PHP has a limitations in upload sizes specially on 32 bit systems, however uploading a big file (2GB) over the HTTP is may be not a good idea, one good solution is using PHP [FTP extension functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.ftp.php).

Comment: This looks like it would only work for files that are already on the server, I want to upload the file from a website to the server.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there's no limit to the size of the file, what you have to check is that both `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` have a settings that would allow 2048 MB at least like this:

```
upload_max_filesize = 2048M
post_max_size = 2048M
```

The next step would be to check what's the memory limit assigned to PHP, it must always be higher than those two previous values. So basically your server would need at least 3 or 4 GB of RAM, because you'd need to assign at least 2049 or more to the PHP process.

With this part:

```
memory_limit = 2560M
```

This should work, but that also depends on your server's configuration and specs.